# Загадочная полоска только в Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Образовывается загадочная полоска только в браузере **Google Chrome - Версия 48.0.2564.97 m**. Возможно, поведение воспроизводится и в других версиях, я использую последнюю. Причем я проверил в **Opera**, **IE-11**, **Mozilla Firefox**, и там этой полоски нету. Что это за явление, и как лучше от этого избавиться?

**ВАЖНО**: через сервис типа  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zsacqez/) работать не будет.
Нужно запускать через index.html в Google Chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Ближе к истине:**
Исходя из последних данных, эта строчка образуется из-за стиля шрифта - **Tahoma** . Возникает следующий **вопрос**, почему это происходит из-за этого шрифта?

---

**Тут, не возникает:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>None</title> 


    <style type="text/css">
        nav > div > ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            nav > div > ul > li.li-1 {
                float: left;
            }
            nav > div > ul > li.li-2 {
                float: left;
            }

        nav > div li a {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


        .nav_div-1 {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }
        .nav_div-2 {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
        }


        .nav_a-1 {
            padding: 6px 16px 8px;
            font-family: Times New Roman,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            color: white;
        }
        .nav_a-2 {
            font-family: Times New Roman,Arial,sans-serif;
            padding: 14px 16px 17px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>


    <nav role="navigation">
        <div class="nav_div-1">
            <ul>
                <li class="li-1">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_a-1" title="The text">
                        <span>The text</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="li-1">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_a-1" title="The text">
                        <span>The text</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_div-2">
            <ul>
                <li class="li-2">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_a-2" title="The text">
                        <span>The text</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="li-2">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_a-2" title="The text">
                        <span>The text</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

---

**Тут, возникает:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>None</title>


    <style type="text/css">
        nav > div > ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            nav > div > ul > li.li-1 {
                float: left;
            }

            nav > div > ul > li.li-2 {
                float: left;
            }

        nav > div li a {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


        .nav_div-1 {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .nav_div-2 {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
        }


        .nav_a-1 {
            padding: 6px 16px 8px;
            font-family: "Tahoma",Times New Roman,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            color: white;
        }

        .nav_a-2 {
            font-family: "Tahoma",Times New Roman,Arial,sans-serif;
            padding: 14px 16px 17px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>


    <nav role="navigation">
        <div class="nav_div-1">
            <ul>
                <li class="li-1">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_a-1" title="The text">
                        <span>The text</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="li-1">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_a-1" title="The text">
                        <span>The text</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_div-2">
            <ul>
                <li class="li-2">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_a-2" title="The text">
                        <span>The text</span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="li-2">
                    <a href="#" class="nav_a-2" title="The text">
                        <span>The text</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>


</body>
</html>
```

---

Разница лишь в этой строке

```
font-family: "Tahoma",Times New Roman,Arial,sans-serif;
```

Comment: Юрий, пожалуйста, перестаньте ставить несоответствующие вопросу метки. Ваш вопрос не относится ни к sass, ни к html5, ни к css3. Приведенный вами пример кода тоже не имеет отношения к sass. У него синтаксис совершенно другой. Это чистый css. По существу: указанная вами проблема не воспроизводится на той же версии Chrome, что и у вас. Вам следует попробовать открыть страницу на проверку с отключенными расширениями или указать больше информации, например, какая у вас операционная система.

Comment: @VenZell Но эта чатсь кода -"//float: right;" относиться к sass. Поправьте меня если я не прав.  Да, хорошо, я сейчас боле данных приведу.

Comment: Нет, это не относит код к sass. У него, повторюсь, другой синтаксис, без использования фигурных скобок и точек с запятой. http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html Такое комментирование не является частью стандарта и его применение это плохая практика, но оно работает и в обычном css. Ваш код не является корректным с точки зрения sass, но является корректным  с точки зрения scss, однако вы не используете ни одной из его возможностей, стало быть это обычный css.

Comment: По поводу комментария с двойной косой чертой посмотрите вот этот ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20192639/2486051

Comment: @VenZell Практика может и плохая, но прямое отношение к sass/scss есть. И почему плохая практика, если этот комментарий валидный и его рекомендует сам производитель языка. Да, я про однострочный  комментарий , который относиться к scss и sass http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments Кстати, почему не является чатсью стандарта, если вы сами же мне скинули офф док. где написано что так можно комментировать.

Comment: @VenZell я почти разобрался в чем была проблема, сейчас опишу подробнее

Comment: Я говорил о CSS. И говорил о том, что использование sass-комментария не делает CSS-код написанным на sass. Прочитайте еще раз. Ссылка на ответ относится к CSS и к тому, что там тоже такие комментарии могут встречаться.

Comment: @VenZel lсогласно официальному источнику, такие комментарии быть не могут, по крайней мере , я не видел что бы так где то упоменалось о таких комментариях.  Вы можете подтвердить свои слова официальными данными? https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments

Comment: Давайте закроем эту тему. Мы говорим о разном, вы меня не понимаете.

Comment: @VenZell Получается теги  'scss' и 'sass' вполне уместны. Так как в официальном источнике по 'css'  нету чёткого обозначения и сопутствующей информации о таком виде комментария, то он относиться к  'scss' и 'sass', согласно официальным источникам по 'scss' и 'sass'.

Comment: @VenZell я обновил свой вопрос, добавил новую информацию.

Comment: скопировал ваш html к себе на комп и открыл в хроме и не увидел эту полоску

Comment: @LenovoID вы точно скопировали два html? У меня на двух разных экранах как минимум, она возникает.

Comment: оба скопировал - и открывал - ни чего нету - ни какой полоски и единственный косяк у вас это в объявление Times New Roman который должен быть заключен в кавычки и всё

Comment: @LenovoID Очень странно. Может у вас не последняя версия хрома? У меня - 48.0.2564.97 m.

Comment: @LenovoID Да, кстати, она видна у меня только лишь при 100% увеличении страницы в браузере.

Comment: @LenovoID Это особенность образуется если слишком большой размер текста.  Просто странно то, что в других браузерах такого нету. Я такого от хрома не ожидал.